# NOT NULL constraint failed: Facture.Mode

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I tried to insert data into table Facture but I received a Crash report on a piece of code :"NOT NULL constraint failed: Facture.Mode (code 1299)".
I didn't find a way ti fix it. Could someone please help me?

There are my logcat.

```
07-22 13:59:01.565 2471-2471/com.example.pc.myapplication E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting U4=100 U1=100 A4=aa Q5=5 Q4=null A3=aaa A5=aa P5=100 P3=100 P4=100 U2=100 Q1=1 P2=100 A1=aa Q2=2 U5=100 Fournisseur=test Q3=3 U3=100 Datefactu=2/07/2018 Numero=123 A2=aaa Mode=null P1=100
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: Facture.Mode (code 1299)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
    at com.example.pc.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.insertFacture(DatabaseHelper.java:178)
    at com.example.pc.myapplication.facture1.onOKClick(facture1.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4720)
```

There is my class facture.java :

```
    public void onOKClick ( View v )
{

    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonfacok) {

        EditText numero = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Etnum);
        EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Etdat);
       EditText fournisseur = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TVfour);
        EditText modepaiement = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TVmode);
        EditText article1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A1);
        EditText article2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A2);
        EditText article3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A3);
        EditText article4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A4);
        EditText article5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A5);
        EditText quantite1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Q1);
        EditText quantite2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Q2);
        EditText quantite3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Q3);
        EditText quantite4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Q4);
        EditText quantite5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Q5);
        EditText unite1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.U1);
        EditText unite2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.U2);
        EditText unite3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.U3);
        EditText unite4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.U4);
        EditText unite5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.U5);
        EditText prix1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P1);
        EditText prix2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P2);
        EditText prix3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P3);
        EditText prix4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P4);
        EditText prix5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P5);


        String strnumero = numero.getText().toString();
        String strdate = date.getText().toString();
        String strfournisseur = fournisseur.getText().toString();
        String strmodepaiement = modepaiement.getText().toString();
        String strarticle1 = article1.getText().toString();
        String strarticle2 = article2.getText().toString();
        String strarticle3 = article3.getText().toString();
        String strarticle4 = article4.getText().toString();
        String strarticle5 = article5.getText().toString();
        String strquantite1 = quantite1.getText().toString();
        String strquantite2 = quantite2.getText().toString();
        String strquantite3 = quantite3.getText().toString();
        String strquantite4 = quantite4.getText().toString();
        String strquantite5 = quantite5.getText().toString();
        String strunite1 = unite1.getText().toString();
        String strunite2 = unite2.getText().toString();
        String strunite3 = unite3.getText().toString();
        String strunite4 = unite4.getText().toString();
        String strunite5 = unite5.getText().toString();
        String strprix1 = prix1.getText().toString();
        String strprix2 = prix2.getText().toString();
        String strprix3 = prix3.getText().toString();
        String strprix4 = prix4.getText().toString();
        String strprix5 = prix5.getText().toString();


        Facture f = new Facture();
        f.setNumero(strnumero);
        f.setDatefactu(strdate);
        f.setFournisseur(strfournisseur);
        f.setMode(strmodepaiement);
        f.setA1(strarticle1);
        f.setA2(strarticle2);
        f.setA3(strarticle3);
        f.setA4(strarticle4);
        f.setA5(strarticle5);
        f.setQ1(strquantite1);
        f.setQ2(strquantite2);
        f.setQ3(strquantite3);
        f.setQ4(strquantite4);
        f.setQ5(strquantite5);
        f.setU1(strunite1);
        f.setU2(strunite2);
        f.setU3(strunite3);
        f.setU4(strunite4);
        f.setU5(strunite5);
        f.setP1(strprix1);
        f.setP2(strprix2);
        f.setP3(strprix3);
        f.setP4(strprix4);
        f.setP5(strprix5);

        helper.insertFacture(f);

            }
      }
          }
```

There is my databasehelper :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4 ;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db" ;
private static final String TABlE_NAME = "contacts" ;
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id" ;
private static final String COLUMN_NOMETPRENOM = "nometprenom" ;
private static final String COLUMN_CIN = "cin" ;
private static final String COLUMN_MOTDEPASSE = "motdepasse" ;
private static final String TABlE_NAME1 = "Argent" ;
private static final String COLUMN_ENTREE = "Entree" ;
private static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date" ;
private static final String TABlE_NAME2 = "Facture" ;
private static final String COLUMN_NUMERO = "Numero" ;
private static final String COLUMN_DATEFOU = "Datefactu" ;
private static final String COLUMN_FOURNISSEUR = "Fournisseur" ;
private static final String COLUMN_MODE = "Mode" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Article1 = "A1" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Article2 = "A2" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Article3 = "A3" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Article4 = "A4" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Article5 = "A5" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Quantite1 = "Q1" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Quantite2 = "Q2" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Quantite3 = "Q3" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Quantite4 = "Q4" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Quantite5= "Q5" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Unitaire1 = "U1" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Unitaire2 = "U2" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Unitaire3 = "U3" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Unitaire4 = "U4" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Unitaire5 = "U5" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Prix1 = "P1" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Prix2 = "P2" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Prix3 = "P3" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Prix4 = "P4" ;
private static final String COLUMN_Prix5 = "P5" ;

SQLiteDatabase db;


private static final String TABlE_CREATE = "create table contacts ( id integer primary key not null , nometprenom Text not null , cin Text not null , motdepasse Text not null);" ;
private static final String TABlE_CREATE1 = "create table Argent ( id integer primary key not null , date Text not null , Entree Text not null);" ;
private static final String TABlE_CREATE2 = "create table Facture ( id integer primary key not null , Datefactu Text not null , Numero Text not null , Fournisseur Text not null , Mode Text not null , A1 Text not null , A2 Text not null , A3 Text not null , A4 Text not null , A5 Text not null , Q1 Text not null , Q2 Text not null , Q3 Text not null , Q4 Text not null , Q5 Text not null , U1 Text not null , U2 Text not null , U3 Text not null , U4 Text not null , U5 Text not null , P1 Text not null , P2 Text not null , P3 Text not null , P4 Text not null , P5 Text not null);" ;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context ,DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABlE_CREATE2);
    this.db=db;
}


public void insertFacture(Facture f)
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from Facture" ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null) ;
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_NUMERO, f.getNumero());
    values.put(COLUMN_DATEFOU , f.getDatefactu());
    values.put(COLUMN_FOURNISSEUR , f.getFournisseur());
    values.put(COLUMN_MODE, f.getMode());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article1, f.getA1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article2, f.getA2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article3, f.getA3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article4, f.getA4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article5, f.getA5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite1, f.getQ1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite2, f.getQ2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite3, f.getQ3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite4, f.getQ4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite5, f.getQ5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire1, f.getU1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire2, f.getU2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire3, f.getU3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire4, f.getU4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire5, f.getU5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix1, f.getP1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix2, f.getP2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix3, f.getP3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix4, f.getP4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix5, f.getP5());

    db.insert(TABlE_NAME2,null, values);
}




@Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

          String query2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABlE_NAME2 ;

            db.execSQL(query2);
            this.onCreate(db);
        }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you problem start with Mode=null and you not authorize null

Comment: @crammeur "Mode" must not be null . I declared as string but no result

Answer (score 0):

Mode's value as per `Error inserting U4=100 U1=100 A4=aa Q5=5 Q4=null A3=aaa A5=aa P5=100 P3=100 P4=100 U2=100 Q1=1 P2=100 A1=aa Q2=2 U5=100 Fournisseur=test Q3=3 U3=100 Datefactu=2/07/2018 Numero=123 A2=aaa Mode=null P1=100`

is null, you have defined the table so that it cannot be null as per `.... , Mode Text not null , ....`.

You either need to pass a Facture object, to the insertFacture method,  that provides, or results in a non-null value being used (which could be to only set the ContentValue for the column if Mode is not null) or you need to remove the not null constraint from the column's definition.

Re comment

> @crammeur "Mode" must not be null . I declared as string but no result

When you declare a variable it's value will be null (unless it's a primitive type).

One get around could be to use the following as the `insertFacture` method :-

```
public void insertFacture(Facture f) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from Facture" ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null) ;
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_NUMERO, f.getNumero());
    values.put(COLUMN_DATEFOU , f.getDatefactu());
    values.put(COLUMN_FOURNISSEUR , f.getFournisseur());
    if (f.getMode != null ) {
        values.put(COLUMN_MODE, f.getMode());
    } else {
        values.put(COLUMN_MODE,"No mode supplied");
    }
    values.put(COLUMN_Article1, f.getA1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article2, f.getA2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article3, f.getA3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article4, f.getA4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Article5, f.getA5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite1, f.getQ1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite2, f.getQ2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite3, f.getQ3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite4, f.getQ4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Quantite5, f.getQ5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire1, f.getU1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire2, f.getU2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire3, f.getU3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire4, f.getU4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Unitaire5, f.getU5());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix1, f.getP1());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix2, f.getP2());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix3, f.getP3());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix4, f.getP4());
    values.put(COLUMN_Prix5, f.getP5());

    db.insert(TABlE_NAME2,null, values);
}
```

This would then use a value of **No mode supplied** should the value of the `getMode` method return null. Not necessarily the ideal fix though. The real fix would be ascertain why `f.setMode(strmodepaiement);` is returning null, which may well be due to the Facture's `setMode` method setting Mode to null (or not setting Mode at all).